# Can I add a rotation one time so that it spins?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I imagined it like for example when you add spin to a spintop where you add spin one time and then it keeps Spinning while getting slower. The only way I know how to do it is to make it in the update function but is there a more sophisticated way to do it?

Comment: use a Rigidbody and use either [`GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity = XY;`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularVelocity.html) or [`GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(XY);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html)?

Comment: I did use AddTorque but it didn't work. I also checked if it could be related to the weight of my cube. But that wasn't the Problem either @derHugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed it now. The Problem was most likely that my cube was just too big. I added a huge amount of Torque (rigidbody.AddForce()) and it worked.